# JavaFX How to minimize window on ImageView click?

Tags: java, javafx, onclick, imageview

I tried to minimize a window on ImageView click and Button click. It works with the button but not with ImageView. Here the **code for the Button**:

```
Stage stage = null;

stage = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
stage.setIconified(true);
```

**How can i do it with an ImageView?**

Tried the same code as for the button but this exception comes:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.image.ImageView cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.Button
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us what did you try for the `ImageView`.

Comment: Tried the same code as for the button but this exception comes:


`java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.image.ImageView cannot be cast to javafx.scene.control.Button`

Comment: Then in case of `ImageView`: `stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();` or you can use the following for both: `stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();` as `getScene` method is declared in the `Node` class and both `Button` and `ImageView` are the subtypes of `Node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot cast an `ImageView` to be a `Button` hence the error message.

What you could do is to cast to `ImageView` instead:

```
stage = (Stage) ((ImageView) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
```

But, as the [`getScene`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getScene--) method is declared in the `Node` class, and both `Button` and `ImageView` are subclass of `Node`, you can cast to `Node` in both cases:

```
stage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
```

But in the end to avoid code duplication, you can extract the whole minimizing logic into a method:

```
private void minimizeStageOfNode(Node node) {
    ((Stage) (node).getScene().getWindow()).setIconified(true);
}
```

and you can call this method in the different click handlers:

```
Button button = new Button("I am a button");
button.setOnAction(event -> minimizeStageOfNode((Node) event.getSource()));

ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
imageView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event ->
     minimizeStageOfNode((Node) event.getSource()));
```

Comment: I put now (Node) for both. It works fine (Y). Thank you.